# not able to commit using tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am encountering a problem, evertime i try to commit.The error is:

**Error: Working copy 'C:\SVN Checkout\Branch\Message Center Issue' locked**

What is the problem?

Comment: This may help: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cleanup doesn't work you should use the 'release lock' option in TortoiseSVN. If this doesn't work you'll need to checkout a fresh working copy.

Answer (score 1):

Try `svn cleanup` before commit. It will recursively clean up the working copy, removing locks.

Comment: Actually mine is an android project in which 2 folders are not supposed to be committed coz the change regularly..So when i try to clean up..it says that those 2 folders are not part of working directory.so it doesn't clean up either.

Comment: @Raghav: you should run `svn cleanup` from root folder of your working copy, which is under version control and of course is part of working copy